# How to add value into my combobox options in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have combobox in my windows forms app and I want it to have values on particular options.

Now I can only put an option, and when I choose it - I can get it via

```
combobox.text
```

My target is to list filenames in combobox and have paths to them in values.

Example: Text is= "option1" value which it contains is = "value1", how to do it?

I saw a few topics about it, but they are about 2 years old, maybe something changed, cause these solutions were not so friendly : ]

**UPDATE**

I've got one issue with your solution, Mahmoud Gamal : )

I'm doing it this way:

```
        List<Foo> combo3data = new List<Foo>();

        categories = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\banners\categories\");

        // There are 3 different paths in categories[] array (category1, category2 and 3)

        Foo categoryInsert = new Foo();

        foreach (string s in categories)
        {
            categoryInsert.path = s;
            categoryInsert.name = s;
            combo3data.Add(categoryInsert);
        }

        comboBox3.DataSource = combo3data;
        comboBox3.ValueMember = "path";
        comboBox3.DisplayMember = "name";
```

After that my comboBox3 has 3 available options (correct) but all of them are the same (same as option #1) - why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the two properties:

- [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx).
- [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx).

In your case, you have to set the combobox's `ValueMember` property to `value1` and the `DisplayMember` property to `option1`.

**Update:** The following is an exmple of how you can populate the items of a combobox from list of some entity `Foo`:

```
public class Foo(){
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 var ds = new List<Foo>(){
     new Foo { Id = "1", Name = "name1" },
     new Foo { Id = "2", Name = "name2" },
     new Foo { Id = "3", Name = "name3" },
     new Foo { Id = "4", Name = "name4" },
 };

 comboboxName.DataSource = ds;
 comboboxName.ValueMember = "Id";
 comboboxName.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

**Update2:** That's because you are adding the same object each time. In the following block of your code:

```
Foo categoryInsert = new Foo();

foreach (string s in categories)
{
    categoryInsert.path = s;
    categoryInsert.name = s;
    combo3data.Add(categoryInsert);
}
```

Each time The `foreach` iterate over the `categories`, all what it does, is changing the same object `categoryInsert`'s values `path` and `name` not creating a new one. Thus, you end up with the same object added in each iteration to the `combo3data`. What you need is create a new `Foo` object inside the `foreach` itself each time, i.e: move the `Foo categoryInsert = new Foo();` inside the `foreach` loop. Something like:

```
foreach (string s in categories)
{
    Foo categoryInsert = new Foo();
    categoryInsert.path = s;
    categoryInsert.name = s;
    combo3data.Add(categoryInsert);
}
```

Comment: U mean I should change combobox into listbox?

Comment: No, that are 2 Properties: `comboBox.ValueMember = "value1";` and `comboBox.DisplayMember = "option1"`

Comment: @pawel, No you haven't the `Combobox` Class already has these to properties as well as the `Listbox` class.

Comment: Hmm, but should I do it after adding the item?

Comment: Could you give me an example of usage?

Comment: @Mahomoud Gamal could you look at update of first post? It seems I have some simple issue, which I can't handle by myself : ]

Comment: Thank you, works now : ) One simple question: When I want get the value of selected item, how should I get it? I can't do it using `string destPath = @comboBox3.ValueMember;`

Comment: ok, nevermind : ) `string destPath = (string)comboBox3.SelectedValue;` works : )

Answer (score 1):

use `comboBox.Text` to set or get the text associated with this combobox.
for Values use `comboBox.ValueMember` for the actual value for the items in the ListControl
or you could also store the values in the `comboBox.Tag`