# Parse variable string

Tags: c#, combobox, string-parsing

I have some Items in a ComboBox. Each Item has an Id and a name.

```
     ______________
    │_____________▼│
    │111  Simon    │              
    │222  Patrick  │              
    │3333 John     │
    │155555 Ted    │
    └──────────────┘
```

I need to pass the Id of the selected item to a stored procedure. I will have to `Parse` part of the item to get only the Id. My problem is, how can I do this when I don't know the length of the Id. (It can be from 1 to 100 characters).

Comment: `comboBox1.SelectedText.Split(' ')`

Comment: What would this return ? 
mySplit[0] = 111 and mySplit[1] = Simon ?

Comment: Are the combobox items simple strings, or are you storing an object related to the list? note that all of the split related answers are returning strings for the ID part....

Comment: I'm storing a string. I'm using a datareader. 

myCombo.Items.Add(myReader["someColumn"].ToString());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split on the space character and take the first result:

```
var id = comboBox.SelectedText.Split(' ')[0]; // Using array index
var id = comboBox.SelectedText.Split(' ').First(); // Using LINQ
```

As an aside:

- If using the mobile framework `ComboBox` class I'd recommend using the [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.mobile.framework.controls.combobox.valuemember%28v=mag.15%29.aspx) property to store the ID and then using this rather than just using the displayed text.
- If using the System.Windows.Forms `ComboBox` you can use the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property to access the ID.
- If using the System.Windows.Controls `ComboBox` you can use the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) proeprty to access the ID.

Comment: I tried both approach but I get an empty string. Any idea why ?

Comment: The string is empty and if I change the Index to [1] I get an Index out of range exception. I should get the name like simon.

Comment: Ooh i found out how to correct this. Your SelectedText.Split does not work. But I changed it for comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ')[0] and now it works thanks. Id still like to understand why the selectedText approach doesnt work though

Answer (score 3):

You have to fill the items into the combobox so that:

```
comboboxName.DataSource = ds;
comboboxName.ValueMember = "Id";
comboboxName.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Otherwise use `comboboxName.SelectedText.Split(' ');` to get these values.

Comment: Same here the second solution returns an empty string. Any idea why ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk, Instead of filling your combobox with `111  Simon │222 Patrick │ 3333 John, etc` you should fill it so that you have a list of id's and names then bind it to the datasource property of the combobox as I explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503240/how-to-add-value-into-my-combobox-options-in-c/11503342#11503342).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var foo = str.Split(' ');  //from 111  Simon will get '111'
var id = foo.Length > 1 ? foo[0] : null; 
if(id != null) {
  //do something with '111';
} else {
   //error
}
```

**EDIT**

I recommend you do it by using a custom `Combobox` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Foo(int id, string name)
    {
        Value = id;
        Text = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

And then add the `object`(foo) into `combobox`:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Foo(111, "simon"));
```

And then you can access the values by casting `SelectedItem` property to your class:

```
//assuming that comboBox1.SelectedText is "simon", the following is true:
var val = (Foo)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
val.Value // 111
val.Text // simon
```

Comment: Maybe with enough error checking to prevent failures? And perhaps getting the first split rather than the second?

Comment: TetsujinnoOni:Thanks for your comment. I fiexed it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try String.Split on the selected response. That will split the text of the selected item at the space. You should get a two-element array, with the first member being the id you represent above.

More broadly, though, you might consider modifying your solution to place the value in the .ValueMember property, and the name in the .DisplayMember property (eliminating the need to parse anything). See if your listbox implementation doesn't support that.

Good luck!